# angular 2, *ngFor checkbox check only one

Tags: jquery, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-cli

I’m trying to create a dynamic list with checkbox using `*ngFor`. Here, i want that the checkbox can be checked only one at a time (if user clicks the 2nd checkbox previously selected one should go unchecked).

```
<div class="img-prev col-md-12" *ngFor="let imgList of uploadedImg; let i = index">
  <div class="col-md-1">
      <input [ngModel]= "selectImg" (click)="updateSelection(i, imgList)" type="checkbox" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your updateSelection method? As checkbox default behavior is multi select, you need to uncheck all checkbox and then select that indexed checkbox.

Comment: You should a radio button if you want only one option to be selected. You can style your radio button to look like a checkbox if you like.

Comment: fixed. understoop.  <input [checked]="selectImg == i" (click)="updateSelection(i, imgList)" type="checkbox" />   updateSelection(imglistIndex,imgFile){
        this.selectImg = imglistIndex;
    }  any one please confirm, is this efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to implement a custom ISelectable interface, something like this.

```
export interface ISelectable {

selected?: boolean;}
```

Then for every object that you want to represent a selectable UI element you can implement ISelectable.

eg:

```
export class SelectableImg implements ISelectable....
```

Then inside your template you can control the [checked] binding with img.selected.

```
    <div class="img-prev col-md-12" *ngFor="let imgList of uploadedImg; let i = index">
  <div class="col-md-1">
      <input [ngModel]= "selectImg" [checked]="imgList.selected"(click)="updateSelection(i, imgList)" type="checkbox" /> 
  </div>
```

Create a deselectAll method:

```
private deselectAll(arr: any[]){
arr.forEach(val =>{
    if(val.selected){
        val.selected = false;
    }
})}
```

And your event handler

```
private updateSelection(selectedOption){

let selected = selectedOption.selected;

this.deselectAll(this.allVals);

selectedOption.selected = !selected;
}
```